# How does Ubuntu lock my Live USB?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, live-usb

I notice that, after booting from my Live USB (with Ubuntu inside) and shutdown, I won't be able to boot it again, unless I unplug the USB and plug it in again.

Is this a side-effect of something, or is it intentional? I wonder what mechanism is used to do this?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is intentional and I'd suspect BIOS or internals of motherboard.

Comment: but at least there must be some way the computer made physical changes to the USB, because I don't think the BIOS can keep any data once the computer is shutdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably caused by some peculiarity of your BIOS. Definitely not intentional.

Comment: hmm now I believe so... I tried on another machine and it wasn't "locked"